# How to create a cross tabulation table using a Dataset?

Tags: dataset, cross

After searching a lot from this forum and @Anton Anton's codes on `Cross Tabulation`, i still cannot find the way to create a dataset table with two-row headers. The first row has two header `Keys`: `First` and `Last`, and the second row header is `{a, b, c, d}` as shown in the following `dataset`:

```
dataset = Dataset[{
 <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}, "d" -> {1}|>,
 <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}, "d" -> {1}|>,
 <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}, "d" -> {1}|>,
 <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}, "d" -> {1}|>,
 <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}, "d" -> {1}|>,
 <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}, "d" -> {1}|>}]
```

Can some show me how to create a dataset table in which the key `First` should be above `a` and `b` together and the key `Last` be above `c` and `d` together?

**EDIT**
Actually, no need for an image of the desired output. Here are the header `Keys`:

```
(*top row header*)
head1 = {"First", "Last"} (* where its elements are defined as *)
"First" -> {"a", "b"}
"Last" -> {"c", "d"}

(*second row header under the top row*)
head2={"a", "b","c", "d"}
```

**EDIT 1**
Here is an image of the format I am after.

[image]

Comment: @rhermans: Since I cannot create an input form `Code` for showing the desired output format, I will edit my question with an image of the desired format.

Comment: @rhermans: In your comment, you are asking for the `Code` I am after. I cannot put the desired output in `Raw Input Form` but I edited the question with extra info.

Comment: @rhermans: My question is really a simple one (from my perspective). Sorry that it is not clear to readers. I just want the `dataset` given in the question to have `two rows of Keys`. In the top row, there are two variables (`First` and `Last`) and in the second row, four `Keys` are distributed across `First` and `Last` in the way shown in EDIT.

Comment: Like in here `Dataset[Take[ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}], All, -2], 
 DatasetTheme -> "Detailed"]` with the Moons?

Comment: @rhermans: Thanks for the code. I gave an example of the output I am after.

Comment: I think all the necessary details have been provided and this question should remain open. I would like to see other ways to achieve the same output.

Comment: @rhermans: I get the desired out format with only one tiny revision required (only for a better visual table). I when apply your `Code` to my actual dataset, the output table is transposed. I do not know why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution

The elements with the [`Key`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Key.html) `"First"` and `"Last"` must be an [`Associations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Associations.html) with the desired keys, like in

```
<| "Header"-> <| "key" -> "value" |> |>
```

### Rebuilding by hand

```
dataset[All, 
    <|
        "First" -> <| "a" -> #a, "b" -> #b |> ,
        "Last"  -> <| "c" -> #c, "d" -> #d |> 
    |>&
]
```

### Using [`KeyTake`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyTake.html)

```
dataset[All, 
    <|
        "First" -> KeyTake[ {"a", "b"} ][#],
        "Last"  -> KeyTake[ {"c", "d"} ][#]
    |>&
]
```

### By position using [`Take`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take.html)

```
dataset[All, 
    <|
        "First" -> Take[ #,  2 ],
        "Last"  -> Take[ #, -2 ]
    |>&
]
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: @rehermans: Thanks very much for your effort. This is what I wanted to have.

Comment: @TugrulTemel you get a different output to what I show? or you desire a different output?

Comment: Your answer is perfect and it gives me the exact same output you show in your answer. Maybe, my special actual dataset which has 13 columns create a problem for MMA, and hence MMA prefers to transpose the dataset table for a usable output. I think this is what happens. So, no problem with the question nor your answer.